# Uploading files with PHP results in permissions 600

Tags: php, file-upload, permissions, file-permissions

We have a basic form which allows users to upload a file. The form has an `<input type="file">` and after doing some validation we save the file like this:

```
    if($file_upload) {
        // this is a file that we can upload and manage
        rename($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], ABSPATH . 'path/to/files/file_' . $user_resume_record_id[0]->id . '.' . $file_extension);
```

}

The parent direction where the files get saved has permissions 755. For some reason, the new files we upload arrive with permissions 600 so the users can't see them afterward. What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off using [move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php), which is meant for this precise case.

Besides, this has been reported in the PHP manual ([link here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php#85371)), and the proposed solution is to use chmod() or copy()

Comment: I switched to move_uploaded_file() and I'm having the same problem. Uploaded files still have permissions 600

Comment: this is also reported on the annotated PHP manual... I'll edit my answer to reflect this

Comment: I was wrong! Your solution DID fix my problem. Thanks for your help. I will update my question.